# Why is the player able to jump while falling off of blocks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a 2D platformer game in the Unity Engine and I have implemented double-jump for my character.
The problem is that when the player is falling off of a block, the player can still jump once:
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float dirX = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 14f;
    private bool doubleJump = false;
    private BoxCollider2D coll;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround;
    //[SerializeField] private AudioSource jumpSoundEffect;
    public KeyCode left;
    public KeyCode right;
    public KeyCode jump;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;


    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        coll = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleMovement();
        HandleJump();
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(left))
    {
        dirX = -1f;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(right))
    {
        dirX = 1f;
    }
    else
    {
        dirX = 0f;
    }

    rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
}
private void HandleJump()
{
    if (IsGrounded())
        {
            doubleJump = false;
        }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(jump))
    {
        if (IsGrounded() || !doubleJump)
            {
                doubleJump = !IsGrounded();
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
            }
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(jump) && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
    }
}

private bool IsGrounded()
{
    bool grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, jumpableGround);
    return grounded;
}

}
```

I have tried to make a smaller radius for the player's ground check radius. I have also checked that jumpableGround is set to the correct tile map.

Comment: because doublejump will be false because you didnt jump.

Answer (score 4):

As our friend BugFinder said, it's happening because **doubleJump** variable is false. Try to change a bit your code.

```
private void HandleJump()
{
    var isGrounded = IsGrounded();

    if (isGrounded)
        doubleJump = false;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(jump))
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            doubleJump = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
        else if (doubleJump)
        {
            doubleJump = false;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(jump) && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Basically we only allow the player to jump when he has his feet on the ground or the doubleJump variable is true.
If the player eventually falls, both checks will return false and you will no longer have that problem.